# Change Version of Service Fabric Manifest from command line

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, teamcity, azure-service-fabric

I'm attempting to build a set of Service Fabric applications on a build server. Its standard practice for us to append the build number to the application version.

Service Fabric however, stores three different version numbers, all in XML:

1. Service Manifest Version
2. Code Version
3. Config Version(s)

Is there a way that I can update all of these dynamically? For a single application you could pass a property to `msbuild` but I've tried using `/p:PackageVersion=x.y.z`, but that only appears applicable to NuGet Packages.

I've found [this feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/service-fabric-versioning) of TFS, but I'm trying to build on TeamCity.

Answer (score 0):

The Application version updates are done via simple XML changes in the ApplicationManifest.xml and ServiceManifest.xml.

You can do it yourself using Powershell.

VSTS\TFS has a build\release task definition that does that using powershell, you can find the source [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/ServiceFabricUpdateManifests) for reference.

You could also create custom build actions to transform these files after build, but I still recommend the Powershell approach